# Hide function only works every time i input (Velo Code)

Tags: function, search, hide

I'm new here! I'm trying to make a search function where every time I search, there's a function that hides every 'N/A' labeled button linked to the cms. Now the problem is, I made the function work when it was only two buttons, now it's three there seems to be a delay where the function only works everytime i input. It's supposed to work all the times so the button should be hidden everytime i search or navigate using pagination. (Velo Code attached)

[enter image description her](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoVmy.png)

I tried to use chatgpt and generated a function to work every time i navigate to pages or through search but there always seems to be a delay where my function only triggers every time i input in a search

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.